# Display name on model not being displayed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model class similar to the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ScaffoldTable(true)]
public class TestModel
{
    [Display(Name="Schedule Name")]
    [Required]
    public string scheduleName;
}
```

And in my .cshtml file I have:

```
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.scheduleName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.scheduleName, Model.scheduleName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.scheduleName)
        </li>
```

But for some reason my display name is not showing up (the label shows 'scheduleName')

I swear I have the same code in other classes and it seems to display just fine. Can anyone point out a reason why this would not work?

Comment: build your project and try again

Comment: @Shyju thanks, but i've rebuild the project many times (I've been having the issue for many days now and just decided to reach out for help).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` works on properties. Your `scheduleName` should be a property not "just" a field.

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ScaffoldTable(true)]
public class TestModel
{
    [Display(Name="Schedule Name")]
    [Required]
    public string scheduleName { get; set; }
}
```

Note: According to the C# naming conventions your property names should be PascalCased.

Comment: Ah, that did it. I did not realize that it needed to be a property and not a field.